# Using C++ code in unmanaged C++ AND managed C# project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, project-management, unmanaged

I'm using a C++ library in two different projects.
One is an unmanaged C++ project for testing purposes where the library is included as a static library.
The second is a C# project (for the front end) which uses the library as a DLL.

Is there an easy way to switch between the two settings (static vs. dynamic library, CLR vs. no CLR...) without having to manually change them every time?

Comment: Keep the settings the same.  There are no good reasons I can readily come up with to not make your test project use the DLL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make multiple configurations -- one for the managed C++ to use and another for the C# to use.